# TensorFlow: Loss function modular design

Tags: python, tensorflow, modularity, loss-function, modular-design

I would like to have a few loss functions, e.g.:

```
    def loss_equation(x, a, b):
        """L2 loss for matrix equation `a=bx`."""
        a_test = tf.matmul(x, b)
        return tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(a-a_test))

    def loss_regular(x):
        """L2 loss regularizing entries of `x`."""
        return tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(x))
```

And to be able to find optimal `x` feeding the losses to a custom optimizing function as:

```
    x_optimal = some_optimizer( 
        { "loss": loss_equation,
          "args": [param_a, param_b]
        },
        { "loss": loss_equation,
          "args": []
        })
```

The optimizer should find the best `x` minimizing the sum of specified losses (e.g. in one experiment I have two losses, each with it's own parameters, in another I have five). 
How do I program this modular behaviour in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 1):

```
x = ...

def loss_overall(x):
    return loss_equation(x, param_a, param_b) + loss_regular(x)
loss = loss_overall(x)
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-3)
with tf.control_dependencies(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)):
    train_op = opt.minimize(loss)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    while True:
        sess.run(train_op)
    ...
```

Firstly you should create loss tensor
Secondly, you should define optimizer
Thirdly invoke minimize method to get the train operation

Comment: Is `tf.control_dependencies` necessary?

Comment: Yes, of cause
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization
See a note